# How to enable SD card for Android Automotive OS emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, mediastore, android-automotive, avd-manager

When creating an AVD, I am unable to activate the SD card in the steps below.

- Device manager -> Create Device -> Automotive(1024p landscape) -> Sv2 API 32 (system image) ->
  Show Advanced Settings(Button) -> Memory and Storage -> Default value is No SD card.

[image]

When creating an AVD, the SD card cannot be activated in the case of Automotive OS.
But the SD card category is enabled in Device Explorer.
So I added mp3 or ogg files to SD card area.
It seems that the external area cannot be accessed in the code.

**[code]**
`
String[] selectionArgsMp3 = new String[{MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp3")};

```
Uri baseUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection,
    selectionMimeType, selectionArgsMp3, null);`
```

**[log]**
    `2023-08-21 14:44:49.749 23045-23092 MusicListWorker         com.example.samplemediaplayer  D  getCursor:**content://media/external/audio/media**`